# Calculate multiple areas with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to calculate different areas within a picture using opencv's `contourArea` without much success. The picture I'm using as an example is the following one:

[image]

My objective is to calculate the table's free area (greyish) and the occupied area (orange objects), and so far managed to print the contours with the following code:

```
img = cv2.imread('table.jpg', 1)

b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
imgRGB = cv2.merge([r,g,b])

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv_channels = cv2.split(hsv)

rows = img.shape[0]
cols = img.shape[1]

for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(0, cols):
        h = hsv_channels[1][i][j]

        if h > 90 and h < 120:
            hsv_channels[2][i][j] = 255
        else:
            hsv_channels[2][i][j] = 0

image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(hsv_channels[2],cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
img1 = cv2.drawContours(imgRGB, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
```

However, I'm facing two issues:

1- The code detects contours inside the circle.

2- Given the multiple contours I don't know if the area returned is the table's, the objects' or both.

Any suggestion?

Thanks a million.

Comment: Is it really for that particular image  only ? As a rule of thumb, do you have other a priori knowledge on the images you have to process (on the place of the orange object) ?

Comment: It's not only for that particular image but for similar ones, in the sense of multiple objects on a surface (with a very different color) and maybe other colors on the side of the surface (such as the floor in this case), but the set up I'm interested in would be very similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you transforming to HSV colorspace have you thought about `cv2.inRange()`? After that you can find contours with `cv2.findContours()` and draw them out of the image, leaving only the gray area.

Example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('tablest.jpg')

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0,0,50])
upper = np.array([160,255,255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

res = cv2.bitwise_and(hsv,hsv, mask= mask)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(res,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for i in contours:
    cnt = cv2.contourArea(i)
    if cnt > 1000:  
        cv2.drawContours(img, [i], 0, (0,0,0), -1)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
cv2.putText(img,'Gray area ='+str(area),(60,90), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5,(0,255,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

EDIT

For calculating percentage:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('tablest.jpg')

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0,0,50])
upper = np.array([160,255,255])

# Calculate whole area
h,w = img.shape[:2]
whole_area_mask = np.ones((h, w), np.uint8)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(whole_area_mask,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
whole_area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

# Threshold the HSV image to get only blue colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

# Bitwise-AND mask and original image
res = cv2.bitwise_and(hsv,hsv, mask= mask)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(res,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

other_area = []
table_area = []

for i in contours:
    cnt = cv2.contourArea(i)
    M = cv2.moments(i)
    cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
    if cnt > 1000:  
        cv2.drawContours(img, [i], 0, (0,0,0), -1)
        if w-100 > cx > 100:
            other_area.append(cnt)
        else:
            table_area.append(cnt)

# Percentage table/napkin/object 1/object 2
table_per = (100*(table_area[0]+table_area[1]))/whole_area
print('Table percentage: ', table_per)
napkin_per = (100*(whole_area-other_area[0]-other_area[1]-table_area[0]-table_area[1]))/whole_area
print('Napkin percentage: ', napkin_per)
first_object_per = (100*other_area[0])/whole_area
print('First object percentage: ', first_object_per)
second_object_per = (100*other_area[1])/whole_area
print('Second object percentage: ', second_object_per)
print('SUM: ', table_per+napkin_per+first_object_per+second_object_per)


cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imwrite('tablest_res.png', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

Table percentage:  9.875440996472028

Napkin percentage:  58.93872849017208

First object percentage:  28.05565555475556

Second object percentage:  3.1301749586003313

SUM:  100.0

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks a lot! Would there be any way to compute the table's area so I can get the percentage of area used/unused for instance?

Comment: When you have have if size > 1000 in the for loop, you alredy have calculated the area of the table without the gray napkin, you just have to distiguish it from the 2 round objects that are put on the napkin and simply add to the area of napkin (that will be your napkin+table area). Then simply calculate the percentage.